# Align view to bottom in UIStackView

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have two UIImageView and one UITextView. 
I want to align second image view bottom as below. How to get this?

[image]

Comment: You can try to set `contentMode` == bottom of second image view.

Comment: A possible solution: Instead of having a single UIImageView, put them into a UIView that will have the whole height, and configure the constraint of the UIImageView to be either on top or on bottom. But contentMode may work too (depends on the UIImage size and the UIImageView size)

Comment: Stack view pointless and in your way in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go...

[image]

**Structure**:

[image]

**Stackview setup**:
(Inner Stackview)

[image]

(Outer stackview)

[image]

**Constraints**:

[image]