# How can I place my container view under my stack view from another class?

Tags: swift

I made a breadcrumb navigation and placed some items in it to show where the user is at the moment. 
In my **ProjectsOverViewController** class is a **IBOutlet** with a **stackView** with some buttons. Outlet for my stack view is in another class and I can´t access it from my **BreadCrumbNavigation**.

---

In my **BreadCrumbNavigation** is a container with some labels and controls. The container is placed randomly in my view. But I want it right under my **stackView**.
[image]

```
let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + self.navigationBar.frame.height, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.config.height))
```

Is there a way to grab the **stackView outlet** and place my container right under it?

Comment: use constraints, try to get the bottom anchor for the stackView and alight your container's topAnchor to the stackView's bottomAnchor,

Comment: in you controller you have stackview and containerView ... whats the issue then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use constraints, try to get the bottom anchor for the stackView and alight your container's topAnchor to the stackView's bottomAnchor,

heres an example similar to your need, hope it helps
[Align view to bottom in UIStackView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318039/align-view-to-bottom-in-uistackview)

Comment: Doesnt work. My stackview is in another class. I cant grab it